# How to put a minimum requirement number for it to write the word

Tags: c#

Can someone edit the code and put a minimum requirement of result "2" for them to show up?

```
        if (!textBox2.Text.EndsWith(" Animals"))
            textBox2.Text += " Animals";
        if (this.textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(this.textBox2.Text);
        }
        if (!textBox3.Text.EndsWith(" People"))
            textBox3.Text += " People";
        if (this.textBox3.Text != "")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(this.textBox3.Text);
        }
```

For example (This is a part of my code, i managed to make it but can't make the upper one) I'm asking because it shows up as "1 Animal Animals" because of the upper code having no restriction:

```
            if (textBox2.Text == "1" && textBox3.Text == "1")
            {
                textBox2.Text += " Animal";
                textBox3.Text += " Person";
            }
```

P.S - I need it to show Animals, People when the result is 2 OR more. NOT JUST 2

Comment: Well can't you just merge the 2 pieces of code together? Making sure that only one of the 2 text-edits gets called?

Comment: I cant but i have no idea how to say that i want it to write the word when the result is 2 OR more, like 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 till 9999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I can understand you want to write a number into a box and then check if there was the string ends with "Animal" or "Animals" etc. Personally I would use integers only, and then check on the numbers and add the string values (animals, persons etc) afterwards.

However, using your approach and modifying it to take into account the things you need, I've merged the 2 codesnaps together and tried to fix the problem you describe:

```
if (textBox2.Text == "1")
{
    textBox2.Text += " Animal";
}
if (textBox3.Text == "1"
{
    textBox3.text += " Person";
}
if (!textBox2.Text.EndsWith(" Animals") && !textBox2.Text.EndsWith(" Animal"))
    textBox2.Text += " Animals";
if (this.textBox2.Text != "")
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(this.textBox2.Text);
}
if (!textBox3.Text.EndsWith(" People") && !textBox3.Text.EndsWith(" Person"))
    textBox3.Text += " People";
if (this.textBox3.Text != "")
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(this.textBox3.Text);
}
```

This way, if it starts out being 1, "Animal" / "Person" is added. If the textbox has "Animals" OR "Animal" in it, it won't edit further. If not, it will add "Animals". Same goes for persons.

Again - I would highly recommend switching to using ints instead of string formats for this kind of task however!

Answer (score 0):

[Int32.TryParse should help you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Is this helpfull ?

```
int number= 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out number)) { // Convert your text to int if it's possible
    if (number >= 2) {
        textBox2.Text += " Animals";
    }
    if (number == 1) {
        textBox2.Text += " Animal";
    }
}
```